# Calculating the mean, standard error and % in R for a data frame

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame with following structure, `dput(scoreDF)`:

```
scoreDF <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2), Status = structure(c(2L, 1L),
  .Label = c("Fail", "Pass"), class = "factor"), Subject_1_Score = c(100, 25),
  Subject_2_Score = c(50, 76)), .Names = c("ID", "Status", "Subject_1_Score",
  "Subject_2_Score"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now, I need to come up with the % of students who passed and failed, mean of the students who passed and failed, standard error for the same.

For standard error, I have defined a function as follows:

```
stdErr <- function(x) {sd(x)/ sqrt(length(x))}
```

where I expect `x` to be a vector whose standard error needs to be calculated.

I have seen the doc for `ddply`, but I am not able to figure out how to calculate the % i.e. (number of passes)/ (total count) and standard error for the data frame above.

Comment: This is not a reproducible question. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for inspiration.

Comment: no need for `plyr` if I understand your question.  `nrow(Data[Data$Status=='Pass',])/nrow(Data)`. Unless you want to split on `ID`... `ddply(Data, .(ID), summarise, sum(Status=='Pass')/length(Status)`

Comment: @Justin: I was hoping of coming up with a way where I do not have to hard code the values, like `Status == 'Pass'`. This is why I was trying to find something using `ddply`. Is it possible to summarise by `Status` instead of `ID`

Comment: I don't understand how you can calculate `# passes / total` without "hard coding" that fact somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can use tapply to calculate group statistics. If your data frame is called students then to calculate mean by pass/fail you would specify:

```
tapply(students$Subject_1_Score, students$Status, FUN=mean)
```

For the standard error substitute your stdErr function for mean.

If you want to calculate something across multiple columns, you can index x:

```
tapply(students[,2:3], students$Status, FUN=mean)
```

To calculate percent of students that passed:

```
dim(students[students$Status == "Pass" ,])[1] / dim(students)[1]
```

Or by score:

```
dim(students[students$Subject_1_Score >= 65 ,])[1] / dim(students)[1]
```

The above is a dataframe example of this type of vector statement using indexing:

```
length(x[x == "Pass"]) / length(x)
```

To calculate a function across rows or columns you can use `apply`.

Comment: `standard error substitute your stdErr function for mean.` .. but they are not same right?

Comment: The FUN argument is to pass a function to tapply. If you want to use your stdErr function: tapply(students$Subject_1_Score, students$Status, FUN=stdErr)